# How to print only one column in a row of duplicate data?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
                                                 name  ...                 acres
0      Georgia Institute of Technology (Georgia Tech)  ...   400 acres (1.6 km2)
1   Augusta University (formerly Medical College o...  ...  485 acres (1.96 km2)
2                      Georgia State University (GSU)  ...  518 acres (2.10 km2)
3           Georgia Southern University (GA Southern)  ...   700 acres (2.8 km2)
4                     Kennesaw State University (KSU)  ...  384 acres (1.55 km2)
5                          University of West Georgia  ...  645 acres (2.61 km2)

.
.
.
```

I am trying to print:

```
4   Kennesaw State University (KSU)  
25  Kennesaw State University (KSU)
```

yet with my current code:

```
print(df[df.duplicated(['name'],keep = False)])
```

It prints the entire row:

```
 name  ...                 acres
4   Kennesaw State University (KSU)  ...  384 acres (1.55 km2)
25  Kennesaw State University (KSU)  ...  384 acres (1.55 km2)
```

How can I alter my code so that it only prints the name column from the duplicated data? I looked online for a while and was not able to find anything. Thank you.

Comment: `print(df[df.duplicated(['name'],keep = False)]["name"]) `  ?

Comment: `print(df[df.duplicated(['name'],keep = False)]['name']) `?

Answer (score 1):

If the column name is known from the outset (as appears to be the case with your code, where you are specifically look at the `name` column), you can print a dataframe slice that contains only the `name` column:

`print(df[df.duplicated(['name'],keep = False)][['name']])`